# PHP: Force 'Featured' to Top

Tags: php, sql

I have database tables with a column called "Featured", which is either **`y`** or **`n`**.

I'm trying to force any **'Featured'=='y'** to print first (it prints HTML through a `foreach` loop).

Right now it just loads in the order of the index (ID).

I tried adding `ORDER BY Featured` to the end of my SQL query, but it does nothing.

How can I accomplish this?

**I'm using this through a generic function. What can I do to check to see if "Featured" exists without making 2 queries?**

*It breaks the SQL on tables that do not contain 'Featured'*

***I set it up with a `switch` to change the SQL only as needed.. but I would much rather handle this in the SQL statement if anyone knows how to mix `IF EXISTS` in. Thanks for the help!***

Comment: `ORDER BY Featured='y' DESC` should do it. If not, show the whole query.

Comment: Datatype is `varchar(1)`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Answer and the points are yours. Thanks!

Comment: It probably did do something, but in the alphabet n comes before y so it would be the opposite of what you wanted/expected.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using Y and N values, use a more numerical approach like 1 and 0, this way you can use numerical sorting.  But if you really don't want to change your column values, then just do

```
ORDER BY Featured DESC
```

as this will put all the Ys first.

PS: In the future, you'll find it's better to use numbers for boolean (1 and 0), this will give you the ability to add niche features in the future where you'll have a 3rd and 4th scenario (so you can set it to 2 and 3, etc).

Comment: Is there a way to use `IF EXISTS` to check for Featured before `ORDER BY`?

Comment: While I agree a boolean field, should, well, be a boolean, and you're right to mention it, the argument _' will give you the ability to add niche features'_ does not hold water against a char column, which can hold, well, any char you like?

Comment: @Wrikken keep in mind the whole point here is that he needed to SORT by this value, once you start using random chars to present different statuses, you throw sorting right out the window.

Comment: Wait wut? Sorting a-z is a concept beyond mysql?

Comment: @Wrikken what I was getting at is if you add another type and it happens to be Z, then he can't sort and put it on top.  (Yes poor example, but we're talking about conceptual at this point anyways).  From experience, I've learned numbers work better (and if you really want to split hairs, use less bits)

Comment: At the point where you have a list of numbers or letters, and you need 1 on top which is not on either end, or a specific ordering not according to their values, the problems (and solutions) are exactly the same. Length-wise, assuming a single-byte character set (latin1/iso) instead of multibyte (utf-8 et al), storage of `CHAR(1)` = 1 byte, `TINYINT` would also be 1 byte, any other type of INT (or wider CHAR) would require more.